# Firefox, Opera, Flock crash in Snow Leopard 10.6.1

Tags: macos, mac, crash

I have the latest version of Snow Leopard with the updated Flash (r32 if I remember correctly).

Safari runs fine, but the latest downloadable versions of Firefox, Opera and Flock all crash randomly and VERY frequently.

The following is an error message from Opera 10 (memory dump and stack dump are removed)

```
        OPERA-CRASHLOG V1 desktop 10.00 6652 mac
         got signal SIGSEGV at address 122EAE91
```

`Registers:
    EAX=00007500   EBX=122EB101   ECX=71AE3A00   EDX=00000020   ESI=00000700
    EDI=00000000   EBP=BFFFCC88   ESP=BFFFCBD0   EIP=122EAE91 FLAGS=00010206
    CS=0017   DS=001F   SS=001F   ES=001F   FS=0000   GS=0037
    FPU stack:
    3FFA8000000000000000 40058000000000000000 402CFD0D3011103C0000
    BFFF8000000000000000 FFFF000D000D000D000D FFFF002A002A002A002A
    FFFF7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F FFFF7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F SW=0020 CW=037F


Used Libraries:
00001000-0000A000 r-x     /Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera
0000A000-0000B000 rw-     /Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera
0000B000-0000C000 rwx     /Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera
0000C000-0000F000 r--     /Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera
000B4000-000B9000 r--     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.sbdl
000DD000-000E5000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
000E8000-000EA000 r-x     /System/Library/TextEncodings/Unicode Encodings.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Unicode Encodings
000EA000-000EB000 rw-     /System/Library/TextEncodings/Unicode Encodings.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Unicode Encodings
000EB000-000EE000 r--     /System/Library/TextEncodings/Unicode Encodings.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Unicode Encodings
0065B000-00689000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
006BD000-006BF000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
006BF000-006C2000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
006CA000-006CC000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
006CD000-006CF000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
006D0000-006DC000 rw-     /Library/Fonts/MshtakanRegular.ttf
006DC000-006EC000 rw-     /Library/Fonts/Gurmukhi.ttf
006EC000-00723000 rw-     /Library/Fonts/GujaratiMT.ttf
0077A000-0077B000 r--     /System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB Profile.icc
00790000-00793000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
00793000-00796000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
00797000-007AA000 r-x     /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libTraditionalChineseConverter.dylib
007AA000-007AB000 rw-     /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libTraditionalChineseConverter.dylib
007AB000-007AD000 r--     /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libTraditionalChineseConverter.dylib
007AD000-007BC000 r-x     /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib
007BC000-007BD000 rw-     /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib
007BD000-007BF000 r--     /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib
007BF000-007C1000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
007C1000-007C9000 rw-     /private/var/folders/PA/PA-w-It8FPCCJODtqXEDcU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.FontRegistry/annex_aux
007C9000-007E1000 r--     /Library/Fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf
007E100`

Answer (score 1):

problem solved. Font cache was corrupted when I upgraded from Leopard to Snow Leopard.
Ran the following in the terminal, rebooted, all is well!

```
atsutil databases -removeUser
```